# How to put queried data from database in dropdown and buttons clickable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have displayed 4 buttons as seen below through a query:

```
 <?php
                    $sql = DB::getInstance()->get('modules', array('username', '=', $user->data()->username));
                    if (!$sql->count()) {
                        echo 'No data';
                    } else {
                        foreach ($sql->results() as $sql) {
                            ?>
                            <p><button class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="test1"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></button></p>

                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

This outputs four buttons from the query (modules that belong to the logged in user) but the problem is that only one button out of the four is clickable and displays the next page. The js below takes the id of the buttons and redirects to the next page:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test1").click(function () {
                window.location = "module-options.php?name=" + $("#test1").text();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click on the other buttons except the first one, nothing happens. They are all meant to redirect to the same page as the first. The problem is how to make the other buttons clickable. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: The `<select>` and `</select>` should not be inside the loop, only the `<option>`s should be. But as to what you're actually asking...I don't have any clue what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My question is how to make the buttons clickable as only one of them is clickable. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to put the SELECT tag outside of the foreach loop. You can change your loop statement to something like this:

```
if (!$sql->count()) {
    echo 'No data';
} else {
    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($sql->results() as $sql) {
        echo '<option value="module">' . $sql->name . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Note that your value for all OPTION tags are the same. That might cause you problems.

In regards to your button-question, your code shows only one button is generated. What "others" are you referring to? Assuming your replicating this:

```
<p><button class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="test"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></button></p>
```

by putting it inside your foreach loop, then one problem is that you are using the same ID for each button. You should only have one ID per HTML element entity. If you just need the ID so you can reference the element(s) in javascript, then you can make it a class and reference them like this:

```
<p><button class="test btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></button></p>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".test").click(function () {
             window.location = "#?name=" + $(this).text();
         });
     });
</script>
```

The selector (".test") means any element that has "test" as a class. The $(this).text() will output the text of whichever element, that has "test" as a class, got clicked.

Comment: The selects were not echoed in the foreach so the problem was fixed in the second part of the answer